# Is it possible to both scan to find an item, then update it in a transcation in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm writing an application using Lambda and DynamoDB that has a table full of codes that can be marked as open or redeemed. I want to scan the table to find 1 open code, then update it to mark it as redeemed. However this seems to involve the potential issue of another concurrent Lambda function also scanning, finding the same code while it is open, then both marking it as redeemed.

Thus my solution was to put the scan and the update in a transaction, however from what I can tell you can only either get items in a transaction, or write items in a transaction, and not both.

The structure of my table is fairly simple:

```
{
   "code": "some code", (primary key)
   "status": "open|redeemed",
   ... other metadata
}
```

Using a traditional relational database the process would be simple, and look something like this:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT code FROM codes WHERE status="open" limit 1;
UPDATE codes SET status="redeemed" WHERE code=%s;
COMMIT;
```

Is there a way to do atomically find and update 1 record using a non-key attribute? Or will I have to find another solution, and are there solutions to this problem?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your access pattern.  Can you clarify what you mean by "scan the table to find 1 open code"?  Are you fetching a specific "deal" by it's code, or just randomly selecting a code with an open status?

Comment: @SethGeoghegan I want to select any open code arbitrarily. In the end I added a secondary index to keep track of which codes are open and which are redeemed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a scan in a transaction, however, there is a way to be sure the item is only used once. If you add an [condition expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html) to your update you can cause the update to fail if another got to it first. You can then catch that exception and try another.

The update would look something like this (using JavaScript DocumentClient):

```
client.update({
  TableName: myTableName,
  Key: { code: codeToRedeem },
  UpdateExpression: 'SET #status = :redeemed',
  ConditionExpression: '#status != :redeemed,
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#status': 'status'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':redeemed': 'redeemed'
  }
});
```